# Unable to find the correlation id in SharePoint log 16 hive

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016

We have an application based on SharePoint 2016.It is generating the log file in 16 hive but SharePoint generated correlation id we are unable to find in log file.
We perform following things:

1. I noticed in **WSS_Logging** database that **ULSTraceLog** Table was not getting created.
2. I checked Monitoring > Review Job definitions in SharePoint central admin and found that Diagnostic Data Provider : Trace Log was disabled.
3. I enabled this job and set the interval of 1 minute.
4. I found the ULSTraceLog table in WSS_Logging database not but still no item in that table.
5. I went to Monitoring > Diagnostic Logging in central admin and found that path set for Trace log is **D:\Program files\Common Files..\16\Logs**.
6. I checked in the above Trace log path for the SharePoint generated correlation ID but unable to find.
7. I have sysadmin access on the database server.

Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the ULS logs file ( from hive folder), you have to check for exact time logs ( by default, every 30 min SharePoint create a new log file).

Another way is run the below mentioned PowerShell to get the logs for a correlation id.

```
Merge-SPLogFile -Path "C:\Logs\FarmMergedLog.log" -Correlation "GUID" -Overwrite -StartTime "06/09/2008 16:00" -EndTime "06/09/2008 16:15"
```

This command will search for uls logs on all SharePoint connected servers in farm and create a log file at the path. Read more about [merge-splogfile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/merge-splogfile?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: I checked this PowerShell command but it is not writing anything in the file.